# Obtaining User-Input After an Operator-Pending mapping is triggered in Vim

Tags: vim

I'd like to create a function intended as `opfunc` (the function called by an operator-pending mapping) for user input in the middle of execution to take an argument. My function should extract a line range from the text motion (can be done using the `[` and `]` marks), then drop the user on to the command line to input an argument (which should be completable, as it is when defining a command), then, on receiving input, continue execution. I will settle also for a situation where the last line of the function drops the user onto the command line, with the prompt prefilled with the name of a command that can take over execution (after the user inputs the argument). How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting off the opfunc example at `:help g@`, here's something to get you started. This stores the range in script-local variables, triggers the command-line via `feedkeys()`, and finishes off with a custom command that can pick up the range.

```
nmap <silent> <F4> :set opfunc=MyOpfunc<CR>g@
function! MyOpfunc(type, ...)
    let s:rangeStart = getpos("'[")
    let s:rangeEnd = getpos("']")
    call feedkeys(':MyCommand ', 't')
endfunction

function! MyCommand( arguments )
    echomsg "MyCommand with" a:arguments "from" string(s:rangeStart) "to" string(s:rangeEnd)
endfunction
command! -nargs=+ MyCommand call MyCommand(<q-args>)
```

Just add the command completion and actual functionality. I'd love to hear about the actual use case you have in mind, too.

Comment: Excellent! This works quite well, I did not know about `feedkeys()`. My use case: I keep track of all my projects/tasks in one big markdown file. I have ctags tag the markdown headers. These represent various projects/task-groups/what-have-you. Over the course of the week, I just add tasks to the top of the file, so they are not organized. They need to periodically be moved under the appropriate section header. My function moves a range of lines under one of these headers, which can be completed with a command since they are tags.